# Debian 10 backward compatibility with eth0

Tags: debian, ethernet, ifconfig

Noticed when upgrading to Debian 10 *(Buster)* that the public `eth0` network interface is now called `ens5` on AWS EC2.

Is there a way to create a symbolic link or similar so that legacy applications that have `eth0` hardcoded can continue to reference `eth0` in tandem with the new `ens5` network interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **systemd.link** for that purpose and rename **ens5** to **eth0**. The interface can be matched based on different criteria e.g. MAC address, PCI slot, Original Name, etc. and then you can *link* it, meaning you can then perform different actions on it, including renaming it.

Here is an example:

```
Example: /etc/systemd/network/10-eth.link

This example assigns the fixed name "eth0" to the interface with the MAC address 00:a0:de:63:7a:e6:

[Match]
MACAddress=00:a0:de:63:7a:e6
[Link]
Name=eth0
```

More info can be found in this Debian Wiki web page: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames
or the systemd.link man page: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/udev/systemd.link.5.en.html